# How to get date from a proprietary

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I am working with DTO data transfer object classes in an asp.net core mvc solution

I have a form with the basic data of a student, I want to record this data with the current date.
Just now I get the date this way

```
    public class StudentVM
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public DateTime CurrentDate { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(StudentVM vm)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        StudentVM student = new StudentVM()
        {
            Name = vm.Name,
            LastName = vm.LastName,
            Age = vm.Age,
            CurrentDate = DateTime.Now
        };

        try
        {
            db.Add(student);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error 123.", ex);
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

I want to initialize my CurrentDate variable, every time I use it I always have the date

```
    public DateTime CurrentDate { get; = DateTime.Now }
```

I want it to look like this

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    StudentVM student = new StudentVM()
    {
        Name = vm.Name,
        LastName = vm.LastName,
        Age = vm.Age,
        CurrentDate
    };
}
```

Comment: A date from a proprietary...what? Also, what problem are you having?

Comment: I want to have an initialized field always with the current date on which the user registers from a property.
Is this possible?

Comment: If I'm not misunderstanding, it seems that you want `public DateTime CurrentDate { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;` ?

Comment: Do you meant "property" and not "proprietary"? If so, look at @John's comment. If you want it read-only, leave out the "set;" part.

Comment: And then you also do not need to add `CurrentDate` when you create a new StudentVM since the value is initialized.